# Split columns in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, split

How can I slipt colum called SOMETHING if it has got values

> "british, born in England 19202013"

into four columns:

> british, England, 1920, 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example. You can replace src.something with your actual field.

**UPDATE**

Updated query to allow for "missing data" within that source string. This also allow the content to be in various different positions, eg "British, born     in       England 1920" and "British  ,born in  England    19202013" will work too. It is quite flexible and tolerant to dirty-data.

*Please mark as answer if this solves your question. TQ.*

```
SELECT  substring( src.something from '(\S+)\s*,')      AS citizenship
    , substring( src.something from 'born\s+in\s+(\S+)')    AS country
    , substring( src.something from '(\d{4})(\d{4})?')  AS fromyear
    , substring( src.something from '\d{4}(\d{4})')     AS toyear
FROM    (
        SELECT 'british, born in England 19202013'::TEXT AS something
    ) AS src;
```

It will return the following result:

[image]

Comment: thank you, that is better solution. And how to put null when there is no country or a date is missed in a record?

Comment: Updated the query to cater to your needs. Please mark as answer if it solves your issue. TQ

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH t(something) AS ( VALUES
  ('british, born in England 19202013'::TEXT)
)
SELECT
  split_part(s[1],',',1) AS col1,
  s[4] AS col2,
  substr(s[5],1,4) AS col3,
  substr(s[5],5) AS col4
FROM t,
  regexp_split_to_array(t.something,E'\\s+') s;
```

Result:

```
  col1   |  col2   | col3 | col4 
---------+---------+------+------
 british | England | 1920 | 2013
(1 row)
```

### UPDATE

In order to populate these values in your table you need to alter table 1st and than perform update:

```
-- add columns
ALTER TABLE t
    ADD COLUMN col1 TEXT,
    ADD COLUMN col2 TEXT,
    ADD COLUMN col3 INTEGER,
    ADD COLUMN col4 INTEGER;

-- perform update
WITH splitted_data AS (
    SELECT
      split_part(s[1],',',1) AS col1,
      s[4] AS col2,
      substr(s[5],1,4) AS col3,
      substr(s[5],5) AS col4,
      something
    FROM t,
      regexp_split_to_array(t.something,E'\\s+') s
)
UPDATE t SET
  col1=sd.col1,
  col2=sd.col2,
  col3=sd.col3::INTEGER,
  col4=sd.col4::INTEGER
FROM (
  SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,something FROM splitted_data
) AS sd
WHERE t.something = sd.something;
```

Comment: ok, thank you. And how to do it on a table in database? I mean to update it? remove old column and paste 4 new columns?

Comment: updated the answer @Mateusz instead of using `col1` etc you can adjust this example to your data model

Comment: ok thank you again! but actualy it doesnt work when some of patterns is missed for eg a date